# Terminal (Mac) create alias that includes user input

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, alias, .profile

In Mac OS Terminal, I'm learning the basics of Unix. I'm having trouble with a hopeful easy fix, but cannot figure out where to start looking.

```
cd __________ && ls
```

That is a pretty common pattern for me, to check and see the file folder I'm working in. To save myself keystrokes, I thought to make an alias in my .profile

```
alias cd='cd && ls'
```

Now, the obvious flaw (which was not obvious to me) was I would not be able to give it a directory to actually change to

```
cd ~/Documents/ && ls
```

This is what I would like to do, but not have to type those last four characters. Any ideas on how I could incorporate my user input (maybe some kind of $(pbpaste) option?

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to first create BASH function for this instead of alias:

```
mycd() { cd "$1"; ls; }
alias cd='mycd '
```

then use it like this:

```
cd ~/Documents/
```

Comment: then you can create an alias of your function :D

Comment: +1 good.. For the OP I'll suggest not to overwrite cd command :P

Comment: An alterative to the alias is `cd () { builtin cd "$1" && ls; }`, although @gtgaxiola's suggestion of not overriding the builtin is a good one.

Comment: Thanks! okay, I'm trying it. It seemed like a bad idea to overwrite `cd` as I was doing it (trapped me in a folder after sourcing it).

This helps!

Comment: most common use of this is find which mac process is using a port , I implemented it writting following in my ~/.bash_profile `get_tcp_port() { lsof -i tcp:"$1"; }
alias who_is_using="get_tcp_port"` and then refresh terminal to use new bash_profile using `source ~/.bash_profile` , then use it like regular alias in terminal `who_is_using 8080`